# Constrain Breaking when all the constrains are satisfied on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have this cell constrains in the interface builder:

[image: Cell Constrains on IB]

And this on UITableViewCell code:

```
public override func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()
    self.contentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) - CGRectGetMinX(self.contentLabel.frame)*2
}
```

The only element which doesn't have a height constrain is the label, that one should expand as the TableViewCell increases height, to deal with the text expansion.

**Yet, I get this error log:**

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1754972f0 UILabel:0x141233ad0.height == 11>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x175497d40 MKMapView:0x141233e30.height == 80>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17149b350 UILabel:0x141233ad0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x141218870.top + 16>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17149b440 MKMapView:0x141233e30.top == UILabel:0x141233ad0.bottom + 13>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x171499280 UITableViewCellContentView:0x141218870.bottom == UILabel:0x141233c80.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x171499640 UILabel:0x141233c80.top == MKMapView:0x141233e30.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1714997d0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x141218870.height == 44>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x175497d40 MKMapView:0x141233e30.height == 80>
```

Ok, it doesn't break my screen at all, but it's a sign that things aren't working as they should.

**To provide some more information, here's the code of the UITableViewDataSource/Delegate**

```
    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        return cell
    }


    if let unwrapedUnit = self.viewModel.unit {
        let kind = self.viewModel.availableCells[indexPath.row - 1]
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kind.identifier.rawValue) as! UnitDetailTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        switch kind.cellInfoKind {

        case CellInfoKind.Map:
            let mapCell = cell as! UnitDetailMapTableViewCell

            mapCell.titleLabel.text = "mapa"
            mapCell.contentLabel.text = "addres \n City + State"

            mapCell.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(unwrapedUnit.lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(unwrapedUnit.lng))

            cell = mapCell


        /*...*/            
        default:
            return cell

        }
        cell.sizeToFit()
        cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        cell.updateConstraints()

        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()

}

// I have the same implementation on tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:
enter code here
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return CGRectGetHeight(self.titleView.frame)
    }

    let cell = self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! UnitDetailTableViewCell
    let size = cell.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    return size.height+1
}
```

So... any idea what is happening?

Comment: why you combine `autoresizing` with `autolayout` just try to remove all `autoresizingMask` and let me know the result, and do you want to achieve the self sizing cell ?

Comment: The same error pops up, but again, the view work just fine. So I'll remove this piece of code.

Comment: concider removing also `cell.sizeToFit()
        cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        cell.updateConstraints()`

Comment: Ohhh nice, it solved the problem!!! But I had to maintain the         cell.updateConstraints(), because the override implementation. Thanks! Any ideas why that happened?

Comment: I have added an answer, please consider accepting the answer if if solves your issue to help other user find out the best answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `autoresizing` code since you are using `autolayout`

Also there is no need to call

```
    cell.sizeToFit()
    cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    cell.updateConstraints()
```

The system will take care of laying out the views and setting up the constraints, you are not updating the constraints in the first time

Also you may want to move your code of `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to  `layoutSubviews()` no need to override `updateConstraints()`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.bounds.width
}
```